# adding a full list of objects to every object in the list in JAVA

Tags: java, class, list

Hi I have 2 classes in Java, `Gossip` and `Node`, I want that `Gossip` will hold a list of all the objects of `Node` class and I want that each `Node` object will also have that list. I tried to write it in the following way:

```
public class Node {

    private Boolean val = null;
    private LinkedList<Node> list;
    static  Random rand = new Random(); 

    public Node(LinkedList<Node> list) {
        this.list=list; 
    }
    ... the rest of Node functions ...
}
```

and in the `Gossip` contractor:

```
public class Gossip {

    private int count;
    private int n;

    private LinkedList<Node> list;

    public Gossip (int n) {
        this.count = 0;
        this.n = n;
        list = new LinkedList<Node>();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
            list.add(new Node(list));
        }
    }
    ... the rest of Gossip functions ...
}
```

Since I'm used to `C++` I am not sure how it works here and whether this will work like a pointer and each `Node` will have a full list or will each `Node` will only have a list with the `Node`s created before it and itself. Also, I don't need to change the list on the program, just to read from it, but it's interesting, will a change that one `Node` does in the list will affect all other `Node`s's lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one list of nodes and all the nodes have references to this single list.
This is because in the Node constructor the assignment `this.list=list;` doesn't create a copy of the object - it simply makes `this.list` the same as `list`, but remember they both are references (on the stack) to the object (on the heap).

Therefore, if you change the list through one of the nodes, all other nodes will see the change.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one list created in `new LinkedList<Node>();` per one `Gossip`. Later it is passed by reference (pointer like), thus it same list everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `Node` class used outside of the `Gossip` class? If not then you might want to consider making `Node` a private inner class of `Gossip`. That will simplify things because `Node` instances can access the list in `Gossip` without having to have their own reference to it. You'll have to define the list as `final` to do this.

Answer (score 0):

All variables / fields in java that are derived from java.lang.Object are "references" and that is basically exactly the same as a pointer in C++. (Not to be mixed up with C++ references which are *also* only pointers but with a special semantic)
That means int, float and all other primnitives are values and not pointers/references, ofc.